# RedHat 7 Error => Requires : libcrypto.so.10

Tags: php, linux, redhat, centos7, php-5.6

I have a problem when I want to install php 5.6. I removed all php stuff with "yum remove php*". I use Linux RedHat 7 with Repo Remi enabled.

I am using OPENSSL_1.0.2 and a 64 bit OS.

[image]

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install php56
Modules complémentaires chargés : langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Résolution des dépendances
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Le paquet php56.x86_64 0:2.3-1.el7.remi sera installé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php56-runtime(x86-64) = 2.3-1.el7.remi pour le paquet : php56-2.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php56-php-pear >= 1:1.10.5 pour le paquet : php56-2.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php56-php-common(x86-64) >= 5.6.31 pour le paquet : php56-2.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php56-runtime pour le paquet : php56-2.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php56-php-cli(x86-64) pour le paquet : php56-2.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Le paquet php56-php-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.35-1.el7.remi sera installé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) pour le paquet : php56-php-cli-5.6.35-1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Le paquet php56-php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.35-1.el7.remi sera installé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php56-php-pecl-zip(x86-64) pour le paquet : php56-php-common-5.6.35-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php56-php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) pour le paquet : php56-php-common-5.6.35-1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Le paquet php56-php-pear.noarch 1:1.10.5-5.el7.remi sera installé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php56-php-xml pour le paquet : 1:php56-php-pear-1.10.5-5.el7.remi.noarch
--> Traitement de la dépendance : php56-php-posix pour le paquet : 1:php56-php-pear-1.10.5-5.el7.remi.noarch
---> Le paquet php56-runtime.x86_64 0:2.3-1.el7.remi sera installé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : environment-modules pour le paquet : php56-runtime-2.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Traitement de la dépendance : /usr/sbin/semanage pour le paquet : php56-runtime-2.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Le paquet environment-modules.x86_64 0:3.2.10-0.el7.remi sera installé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : libtcl8.5.so()(64bit) pour le paquet : environment-modules-3.2.10-0.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Le paquet php56-php-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.35-1.el7.remi sera installé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) pour le paquet : php56-php-cli-5.6.35-1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Le paquet php56-php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.10-1.el7.remi sera installé
---> Le paquet php56-php-pecl-zip.x86_64 0:1.15.2-1.el7.remi sera installé
---> Le paquet php56-php-process.x86_64 0:5.6.35-1.el7.remi sera installé
---> Le paquet php56-php-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.35-1.el7.remi sera installé
---> Le paquet php56-runtime.x86_64 0:2.3-1.el7.remi sera installé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : /usr/sbin/semanage pour le paquet : php56-runtime-2.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Traitement de la dépendance : /usr/sbin/semanage pour le paquet : php56-runtime-2.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Résolution des dépendances terminée
Erreur : Paquet : php56-runtime-2.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
         Requiert : /usr/sbin/semanage
Erreur : Paquet : php56-php-cli-5.6.35-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
         Requiert : libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
Erreur : Paquet : environment-modules-3.2.10-0.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
         Requiert : libtcl8.5.so()(64bit)
 Vous pouvez essayer d'utiliser --skip-broken pour contourner le problème
 Vous pouvez essayer d'exécuter : rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: please paste your code in the question, don't rely only on external links

Comment: i added my code in the question, thank you :)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like RHEL 7.4 [switched from OpenSSL 1.0.1e to 1.0.2](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1462343):

> openssl on RHEL7 is originally based on openssl-1.0.1e but was rebased to openssl-1.0.2k with RHEL7.4

I guess this means you're using <7.4 but Remi builds his PHP RPMs with 7.4+. I think your options are:

- upgrade your server to 7.4 or later
- take Remi's SRPMs and rebuild PHP 5.6 yourself, adjusting the openssl version in the specfile if necessary (but it'll probably just work)

You could look back through his RPMs to find a version of PHP 5.6 built before 7.4, but this is a bad idea because you'd be missing recent security fixes.

Comment: Indeed... as explained in the FAQ... https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#deps